# Good Distro to develop a gamer console distro

Tags: kernel

What is a good distro to develop a system software for my own game console? I am looking to develop an OS for 2 game consoles I have designed. One is a cheep yet powerful base console, and the other is a raspberry pi based handheld. What is the best distro to do this with?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: Well, it could be "which version of Ubuntu is good for this," but the question is still primarily opinion based.

Comment: and there are 2 options to pick from: lts or not lts. But that choice is NOT about "good distro to develop a gamer console distro".

Answer (score 1):

Well, being that this is AskUbuntu, I would say, from personal experience, on a RPi 2/3 I would use Ubuntu Mate, and base Ubuntu 17.10 on the main computer. If specs are iffie, I would use Lubuntu or Xubuntu for low hardware requirements.